# Another BCD byte[] to int and back again

Tags: c#, encoding, bcd

Im having trouble with some conversions, and can´t find whats wrong with the code,
or with the idea of what it has to do.

I have the following byte[]

```
byte[] bytes = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE};
```

which I convert into ulong this way:

```
ulong next = ((uint)((((0x00 << 4) | bytes[0]) << 16) | ((bytes[1] << 8) | bytes[2])));
```

next thing I add 1 to next:

```
next++;
```

Then, I want to convert the ulong, back to the byte array. I tryed with several bcd algorithms found here and on the web, but I cannot get the result I am expecting:

```
byte[] bytes = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
```

insted of

```
{ 0x15, 0x72, 0x77, 0x16}
```

which I am getting with most of the solutions I have tryed.

Here is one of the algorithms I have used:

```
static Byte[] CopyAsBCD(UInt32 value)
        {
            Byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            Int32 offset = 0;
            var length = 4;
            var s = value.ToString();
            var stringIndex = s.Length - 1;
            var bufferIndex = offset + length - 1;
            var isLower = true;

            try
            {
                while (bufferIndex >= offset && stringIndex > -1)
                {

                    if (isLower)
                        buffer[bufferIndex] = Byte.Parse(s[stringIndex].ToString());
                    else
                        buffer[bufferIndex] += (Byte)(Byte.Parse(s[stringIndex].ToString()) << 4);

                    if (!isLower)
                        bufferIndex--;
                    isLower = !isLower;
                    stringIndex--;
                }

            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return buffer;
        }
```

What I am doing wrong? or I have a concept problem?

Comment: So you are trying to convert the byte array to an int? What are you expecting back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just use:

```
//Array padded to 8 bytes, to represent a ulong
byte[] bytes = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE};

var longBytes = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);

var arrayBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(longBytes);
```

Note: you may need to reverse the array, depending on the [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the system you're on (in which case you may need to add padding to the other side).

Comment: i'll try this and let you know.

Comment: You may have to reverse your byte array (bytes.reverse()), depending on the endianness of your system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Oh - your byte array needs to be padded to 8 bytes for a uLong - byte[] bytes = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE};

Comment: Have to do 1 or two things around, and reverse things, in order to make the addition work. Thanks!